# Contradiction of a statement?

Tags: logic

My textbook has asked me to find the "contradiction" of a given statement but I have not learned to do such a thing and googling has not yielded in any results whatsoever. Exactly what is the contradiction of a statement and how to form it, given any statement?

**Edit**: This is the problem in question:

> "Write the converse, contrapositive and contradiction of the statement "If ∆ABC is right angled at B, then AB²+BC²=AC²"

The answer for the contradiction of this statement is given as

> "∆ABC is right angled at B and AB²+BC²≠AC²"

Comment: Never heard of that.. maybe it meant negation? or converse, in case of an implication?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not *contrapositive*? What textbook are you using? Can you upload a relevant paragraph?

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure that they mean neither the converse, nor the contrapositive.

Comment: From the answer, it is clear that the "contradictory" of $A$ is $\lnot A$. see example: the statement is : "If $p$, then $q$" and its *contradiction* (I would prefer: *contradictory*) is : "$p$ and **not** $q$".

Comment: I think (with @AngeloRendina ) that "contradiction" here means "negation". Can you find places in your textbook where the author uses either term? I've upvoted the question - clearing up textbook vocabulary is important.

Comment: See [contradictory](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contradictory).

Comment: Actually, my textbook does use the term "negation" quite distinguishably. However, I think it's using this term with "contradiction" interchangeably. Now I need to make sure that I have got it right by looking up whether this is the case by solving some more problems. I will post again, if I find that this is indeed the case. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be asking, when you (your text) refers to the "contradiction" of a statement, might be better termed as the "negation" of a sentence. For example, if person A declares $p$, another person B would be contradicting A by declaring "not $p$. That is, person B is asserting the negation of $p$.

So, we have a sentence we'll call $p$.  It's negation is simply $"\lnot p".$
So if we know that $p$ is true, its negation would be false.

If the sentence (proposition), for example, is "$x$ is an odd number", it's negation would be "it is not the case that $x$ is an odd number," or equivalently, its negation would be "$x$ is an even number."

Answer (score 0):

a contradiction is a statement which is always false,  like P and notP.

for example if we have a<1  and we find that a>1, there is a contradiction.

a statement whis is always true is called a tautology ( tautologie in french).
for example :
the square of a real is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use formal approach.

Let $$A = \text{∆ABC is right angled at B},$$
$$B = \text{AB²+BC²=AC²}.$$

Then your first statement is $A \to B$ that is equal to $\neg A \vee B$. The contradiction (using de Morgan's theorem) is $\neg(\neg A \vee B) = A \& \neg B$. And this stands for exactly *'∆ABC is right angled at B and AB²+BC²≠AC²'*.

Comment: Yes, I see now that the terms "contradiction" and "negation" can be used interchangeably. Thanks :-)